# Database of surface electronic structure

Tags: density-functional-theory, electronic-structure, surfaces, databases, transition-metals

I'd like to compare my simulation result of a TiO2-110 surface's electronic structure, but all the literature shows too many different results, so I'd like to look for a database for surface electronic structure. Is there any database for this purpose?

Comment: +1. I might be able to write an answer based on my own work on electronic structure databases. I've added the question to [this list](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/5). At present I've been very busy with cleaning up other questions from the unanswered queue. **This question will probably get an answer for sure if it had a bounty on it!**

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question?